# I can't dual boot Ubuntu along side windows 11

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, usb-installation

Today I installed Ubuntu and run it successfully after long time at first it's awful slow while booting(took around 10mins) and performance is slow too, my CPU fans started to run like I am playing some game when I just boot the ubuntu and ran commands `sudo apt-get updates` and `sudo apt install upgrade` after that I restarted Ubuntu and I get same window I always get.[This is the window I always gets if not for black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWngM.jpg)

I am new to Ubuntu this is my first time trying Linux OS. At first I tried to install Ubuntu (around November 2022) it worked fine but i couldn't install ROS so I tried to reinstall from then on it's been three months I couldn't install Ubuntu I always run into problem I tried various YouTube tutorials all of them are pretty much same. I downloaded ISO file dozens of times and used blena Etcher and rofus for flashing. The Ubuntu always shows its installed and ask to restart after that I wither get a black screen or screen like the image I shared above.

I followed this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/QKn5U2esuRk) at end of the video he also mentions how to remove Ubuntu I used that method to remove Ubuntu and reinstall every time along side with a comment on cmd at advanced boot options:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

So as I said before everytime it shows Ubuntu is installed but I can't use it. I really appreciate if someone help me resolve this issue.

My system information:

Acer aspire 7
Processor: AMD ryzen 5 5500u
RAM : 8GB
With integrated nvidia GTX 1650
Main OS : Windows 11 Home

As for the ISO file I just downloaded LTS (22.04) version file from official website
I also disabled secure boot and fast boot

Comment: Don't use the nouveau driver for your NVidia card, but the official NVidia driver ( not open source ). During installation, when asked 'how do you want to install Ubuntu?', choose 'something else' and select the unpartitioned part of the disk. And the correct commands are 'sudo apt update' and 'sudo apt upgrade'.

Comment: Acer often requires "trust" on an unknown UEFI boot entry that is really the Ubuntu entry. You have to turn on Secure boot to set "trust" Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702 Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot